# ionic ion-nav-buttons not working in abstract view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Using the ionic framework I'm trying to have an abstract view that contains a nav button, however it does not seem to work:

Index.html

```
<ion-nav-bar align-title="left" class="bar-stable"></ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

Abstract view:

```
<script id="menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view cache-view="false">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
              <button class="button button-icon ion-more"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

Page 1:

```
<script id="page1.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view cache-view="false" title="Page 1">
    <ion-content>
      <h1>This is page 1</h1>
      <a ui-sref="page2">Go to page 2</a>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

Page 2:

```
<script id="page2.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view cache-view="false" title="Page 2">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
              <button class="button button-icon ion-more"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-content>
      <h1>This is page 2</h1>
      <a ui-sref="page1">Go to page 1</a>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

Full code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJxoLb

The page 1 view does not get the nav button, but the page 2 view does, because it includes the ion-nav-buttons directly in it's own view.

If I change the ionic version to beta 13, it does work.

Is this a bug in later versions, or do I need to do something different for this to work i latest versions (beta 14, rc 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is by design: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3332#issuecomment-81850467